# 1.9 Kill syntax

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

So I am trying to make a command block to kill all creepers. The syntax in the command block is:

```
kill @e[type=Creeper, r=10]
```

This command is even directly shown on the [Wiki](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Commands#Target_selector_arguments). I am assuming that the syntax must have changed in 1.9.2, or is there a server setting I am missing that is needed for this to work.
I have tried just the 'kill' command and it kills me, the 'kill @e' again only kills me and no other mobs.

The command block was being hindered by either a permission or a bug in the **essentials** plugin for **spigot**

Answer (score 2):

The command does not work (`The entity UUID provided is in an invalid format`) because the arguments given are invalid, there is a space between these arguments. It should be written like this instead:
`kill @e[type=Creeper,r=10]`

From the [Wiki](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Commands#Target_selector_arguments):

> **Spaces are not allowed around** the brackets, equal signs, or **commas**, and only commas may be used to separate argument-value pairs.

Comment: It still does not kill any of the creepers and does not give me any error messages (it didnt to begin with)

Comment: @JamesTompkins: The command will kill any creepers within 10 blocks (spherical) of where the command is executed.  If you're running the command in a command block, it's only killing creepers that are within 10 blocks of that command block.  If you want to kill creepers in an area around you, but run the command from a command block, you're going to have to learn the `execute` command.

Comment: @JamesTompkins http://i.imgur.com/O5VOI1p.png & http://i.imgur.com/Ow8k24J.png Screenshots taken in 1.9.4.

Comment: I have tested it on my singleplayer and it works. That means it must be an issue with the spigot server. Am i missing something in the server.properties or something?..